# How to division 2 list and multiply a list and array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, math, numpy-ndarray

Concentration

I have the following variables:

```
  data = ['10 20 10 36 30 33 400 400 -1 -1', 
       '100 50 50 30 60 27 70 24 -2 -2 700 700', 
       '300 1000 80 21 90 18 100 15 110 12 120 9 900 900 -3 -3',
       '30 90 130 6 140 3 -4 -4 1000 1000']
  data = [e.split() for e in data]


  weight = [int(weight[0]) for weight in data]
  dose = [int(dose[1]) for dose in data]
  time = [np.array((time[2::2]), dtype=int) for time in data]
  concentration = [(np.array((concentration[3::2]), dtype=int)) for concentration in data]

    
  C_mean = [np.mean(np.log(x)) for x in concentration]
  T_mean = [np.mean(x) for x in time]


  
  a = ((np.subtract(time, T_mean)),(np.subtract(concentration, C_mean)))/(np.subtract(concentration, C_mean))
```

I want to the following:

[image] and  [image]

So attempted the following:

```
     b = C_mean - (np.multiply(a, T_mean))
    
    output: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'substract'
```

and

```
    A = np.multiply(([w / d for w, d in zip(weight, dose)]),((2.71828182846)**b))

   output: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

What can i do to get my A and B values?

Comment: Is `a` a scalar and `A` a vector ? show the values of variable you are using in the question.

Comment: You have a typo in `np.substract` instead of `np.subtract`, but in any case you don't need it.  Just write `b = C_mean - a*T_mean`.    For `A` if `w` and `d` are Numpy arrays just write `A = w / d * np.exp(b)`

Comment: In general, when using Numpy, if some variables `a` and `b`  are Numpy arrays you don't need to use functions like `np.multiply`, etc.  Just operate on them with normal arithmetic operators.  For exponentials however, use `np.exp`

Comment: You need to convert your variables, which are lists to numpy arrays. You can do it like this: `my_array = np.array(my_list)`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Converting my lists to array, is not exactly what i am looking for?  I'll just be doing this to divide my list [w / d for w, d in zip(weight, dose)]

Comment: @Iguananaut Hey, Iguananaut! is see, but the thing is when i try to divide weight/dose i get the following error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list' and if do the np.exp(b) i do not get the full result. I want e^b.

Comment: @mujjiga Yes! i have now updated the post and added all the variables used

Comment: I ran your code and got `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  C_mean = [np.mean(np.log(x)) for x in concentration]`. Please note that your `time` and `concentration` variables are lists of arrays while `weight` and `dose` are lists with 4 elements.

Comment: "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list' and if do the np.exp(b) i do not get the full result" yes, because you need to convert them to Numpy arrays.